# Using a contain in a find with HABTM relationship in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a HABTM relationship between Entities and Countries. The following find returns the data I want but I want to whittle it down to returning just the ticker field from entities:

```
$blap = $this->Entity->Country->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Country.id' => 78)));
```

So I added a contain like this:

```
$blap = $this->Entity->Country->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Country.id' => 78),'contain'=>'Entity.ticker));
```

but that had no effect.

I tried calling contain on the Entity model before calling the find like this:

```
$this->Entity->contain('ticker');
$blap = $this->Entity->Country->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Country.id' => 78)));
```

But that generated the following error message

> 27    contain 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'contain' at line 1            0 28    SELECT `Country`.`id`,
>   `Country`.`name`, `Country`.`hash` FROM `countries` AS `Country` WHERE
>   `Country`.`id` = 78 LIMIT 1       1   1   1 29    SELECT `Entity`.`id`,
>   `Entity`.`ticker`, `Entity`.`shares_outstanding`,
>   `Entity`.`begin_fiscal_calendar`, `Entity`.`last_reported_quarter`,
>   `Entity`.`next_report_date`, `Entity`.`obsolete_groups`,
>   `Entity`.`actual_fiscal_year_end`, `Entity`.`full_name`,
>   `Entity`.`depricated`, `Entity`.`obsolete_country_id`,
>   `Entity`.`ticker2`, `Entity`.`hash`, `CountriesEntity`.`id`,
>   `CountriesEntity`.`country_id`, `CountriesEntity`.`entity_id`,
>   `CountriesEntity`.`default_country` FROM `entities` AS `Entity` JOIN
>   `countries_entities` AS `CountriesEntity` ON
>   (`CountriesEntity`.`country_id` = 78 AND `CountriesEntity`.`entity_id`
>   = `Entity`.`id`)      32  32  1

As a backup plan I can write code to sift through the results in $blap and pull out the values I want but I thought that there would be some way to filter within the find command itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are calling find on `Country` model it is the one you should contain, like this: `$this->Entity->Country->contain()`.

Also, you can't put fields directly on the contain call. 
Try calling like this: `$this->Entity->Country->contain(array('fields' => 'ticker'))`.